# QSharedPointer::create()

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, qt5, qsharedpointer

In Qt 4 i have I have the following array:

```
QSharedPointer<unsigned char> encrypted(new unsigned char[RSA_size(publickey)]);
```

How can I combine the two allocations in one with the new Qt 5 create function?

```
QSharedPointer<T> QSharedPointer::create()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first example is wrong and will not only leak memory, but cause UB. When you define a `QSharedPointer<unsigned char>` you are defining a *smart pointer* for a single element, not an array of elements, therefore `delete` will be called, not `delete[]`.

Change it to:

```
QSharedPointer<unsigned char> encrypted(new unsigned char[RSA_size(publickey)], [](unsigned char* x){ delete[] x; });
```

That is: you have to provide a custom deleter for the pointer.

Finally, the `QSharedPointer::create` function is supposed to be used only for one element, not an array of elements and it can be used with:

```
auto x = QSharedPointer<unsigned char>::create();
```

Comment: I can't find this method in docs, could you give a link, please?